# How to navigate using vue router from Vuex actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am creating a web app with Vue 2.x and Vuex 2.x. I am fetching some information from a remote location via an http call, I want that if that call fails I should redirect to some other page.

```
GET_PETS: (state) => {
  return $http.get('pets/').then((response)=>{
      state.commit('SET_PETS', response.data)
    })
  },
  error => {this.$router.push({path:"/"}) }
  )
}
```

But `this.$router.push({path:"/"})` gives me following error.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

How can this be achieved.

Simulated JsFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pukx3heb/1/)

Comment: it is because you are using it inside an arrow function that treats 'this' as a literal. either convert it to a regular function or use the suggested answers below...

Answer (score 230, accepted):

As long as you're exporting your router instance from somewhere in your app (e.g. `./router.js`), you can `import` it for use anywhere you want– including into Vuex stores:

```js
import router from './router';
```

From there, you can use `router.push()`.

Simple like that.

Comment: not working on quasar v2

Module not found: Can't resolve imported dependency "./router"

Answer (score 22):

This example may help you.

### main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

...

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'hash',
    base: "./",
    routes: [
        { path: "/", component: welcome},
        { path: "/welcome", component: welcome},

    ]
})
```

### actions.js

```
import {router} from "../main.js"

export const someAction = ({commit}) => {

    router.push("/welcome");
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should use Vue. Actions shouldn't have side effects. Solve this in methods of the component like `dispatch('someAction').then(() => this.$router.push('/welcome'))`

Comment: @adriaan not stricyly true, even the actions in the vuex demos have sideeffects.

Comment: @adriaan Actions can in fact have as many side effects, it's literally their purpose to handle non-deterministic and asynchronous logic.
 Mutations are the ones where there should strictly be no side effects.

Comment: I guess my comment is invalid then. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @adriaan You was thinking of mutations and getters

Comment: I think so too. I'm coming from Ember.js, I think I didn't update my documentation in my head yet :)

Answer (score 12):

**INITIAL ANSWER**

In `main.js` (the one, where we "install" all modules and create `Vue` instance, i.e. `src/main.js`):

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  apolloProvider,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})

export { vm }
```

This is my example, but in our case the most important here is `const vm` and `router`

In your `store`:

```
import { vm } from '@/main'

yourMutation (state, someRouteName) {
  vm.$router.push({name: someRouteName})
}
```

P.S. Using `import { vm } from '@/main'` we can access anything we need in `Vuex`, for example `vm.$root` which is needed by some components of `bootstrap-vue`.

P.P.S. It seems we can use `vm` just when everything is loaded. In other words we can not use `vm` inside `someMutation` in case, if we call `someMutation` inside `mounted()`, because `mounted()` comes/occurs before `vm` is created.

---

**NEW ANSWER**

Constantin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736916/4992248) (the accepted one) is better than mine, so just want to show for novice how to implement it.

Inside core dir (inside `/src` in my case), next to `App.vue`, `main.js` and others I have `router.js` with the content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

// Traditional loading
import Home from '@/components/pages/Home/TheHome'

// Lazy loading (lazy-loaded when the route is visited)
const Page404 = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Page404" */ '@/components/pages/404)
const Page503 = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Page503" */ '@/components/pages/503)

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'Page404',
      component: Page404
    },

    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'Page503',
      component: Page503
    },

    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },

    // Other routes
    {....},
    {....}
  ]
})

// Global place, if you need do anything before you enter to a new route.
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  next()
})

export default router
```

Import our router to `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

export { vm }
```

Finally, inside your component, or Vuex or anywhere else `import router from './router'` and do whatever you need, such as `router.push(...)`

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you aren't injecting your router into your app, hence it being 'undefined'

In previous versions of vue-router you would: `Vue.use(VueRouter)`, with 2.0 you can inject the router into the app like below:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router // inject the router
}).$mount('#app')
```

this should then make it available as `this.$router` throughout the app

---

Following answering a related question: [How to use Vue Router from Vuex state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767874/how-to-use-vue-router-from-vuex-state/40768840#40768840) it seems that Vuex won't receive the router instance at `this.$router`. Therefore two methods were suggested to provide access to the router instance.

The first is more direct which involves setting a webpack global to the instance.

The second involves using Promises with your vuex action that would allow your components to utilise their reference to the router instance following the actions Promise resolving / rejecting.

Comment: This should be the answer specifically for vue 2

Answer (score 7):

I didn't like keeping my app's location state separate from the rest of my app state in the Store, and having to manage both a Router and a Store, so I created a Vuex module that manages the location state *inside* the Store.

Now I can navigate by dispatching actions, just like any other state change:

```
dispatch("router/push", {path: "/error"})
```

This has the added benefit of making things like animated page transitions easier to handle.

It's not hard to roll your own `router` module, but you can also try mine if you want to:

https://github.com/geekytime/vuex-router

Answer (score 4):

You can simply import route from router directory like this:

```js
import router from '@/router'

router.push({name: 'Home'})
```

this **@** symbol replaces the path to the src directory