# How to use Vue Router from Vuex state?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

In my components I've been using:

`this.$router.push({ name: 'home', params: { id: this.searchText }});`

To change route. I've now moved a method into my Vuex actions, and of course `this.$router` no longer works. Nor does `Vue.router`. So, how do I call router methods from the Vuex state, please?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736799/how-to-navigate-route-from-vuex-actions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm assuming [vuex-router-sync](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync) won't help here as you need the router instance.

Therefore although this doesn't feel ideal you could set the instance as a global within webpack, i.e.

```
global.router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
  ...
```

now you should be able to: `router.push({ name: 'home', params: { id: 1234 }})` from anywhere within your app

---

As an alternative if you don't like the idea of the above you could return a Promise from your action. Then if the action completes successfully I assume it calls a mutation or something and you can `resolve` the Promise. However if it fails and whatever condition the redirect needs is hit you `reject` the Promise.

This way you can move the routers redirect into a component that simply catches the rejected Promise and fires the vue-router push, i.e.

```
# vuex
actions: {
  foo: ({ commit }, payload) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (payload.title) {
        commit('updateTitle', payload.title)
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject()
      }
    })

# component
methods: {
  updateFoo () {
    this.$store.dispatch('foo', {})
      .then(response => { // success })
      .catch(response => {
        // fail
        this.$router.push({ name: 'home', params: { id: 1234 }})
      })
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works - thanks. Why is it a bad idea to attach router to global? Similarly, I need global access to Vue-Resource - for some reason importing Vue and using Vue.http works fine (but is it optimal?) whereever I need Vue-Resource. Should I attach Vue-Resource to global as well? Regarding your second point, I will look into that (I don't much understand promises)

Comment: I'm not really sure that it is a bad idea, it just feels a bit wrong - like this should be something built into **vuex-router-sync**. I've elaborated on the second idea just in case as I really like Promises! On your point with vue-resource, yeah that's fine - `Vue.http` is intended to be used this way, no need to make that global.

Comment: I'm having trouble with my Promise syntax - would you mind taking a second to look? http://jsbin.com/webezelaki/edit?js

Answer (score 1):

I a situation, I find myself to use `.go` instead of `.push`.

Sorry, no explanation about why, but in my case it worked. I leave this for future Googlers like me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `rootState.router` will be available in your actions, assuming you passed `router` as an option in your main Vue constructor.

As GuyC mentioned, I was also thinking you may be better off returning a promise from your action and routing after it resolves. In simple terms: `dispatch(YOUR_ACTION).then(router.push())`.

Comment: Yes, I did ultimately go with the Promise approach that GuyC mentioned. How did you learn / how are we expected to know about rootState? Haven't seen that documented anywhere.

Comment: Yeah it probably isn't given the emphasis in the docs it should be. It's sort of mentioned in the Vuex [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) documentation and otherwise only mentioned in the [modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html) documentation - it definitely doesn't jump out at you.

Comment: There is no `router` in the rootState by default. Injecting it manually would also be overkill, as the router instance is mostly immutable, except for the `route` itself, which is part of the state if using vuex-router-sync.

Answer (score 0):

```
    state: {
        anyObj: {}, // Just filler
        _router: null // place holder for router ref
    },
    mutations: {
        /***
        * All stores that have this mutation will run it
        *
        *  You can call this in App mount, eg...

        *  mounted () {
        *    let vm = this
        *    vm.$store.commit('setRouter', vm.$router)
        *  }
        *
        setRouter (state, routerRef) {
            state._router = routerRef
        }
    },
    actions: {
        /***
        * You can then use the router like this
        * ---
        someAction ({ state }) {
            if (state._router) {
                state._router.push('/somewhere_else')
            } else {
                console.log('You forgot to set the router silly')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

After I published this answer I noticed that defining it the way I presented Typescript stopped detecting fields of `state`. I assume that's because I used `any` as a type. I probably could manually define the type, but it sounds like repeating yourself to me. That's way for now I ended up with a function instead of extending a class (I would be glad for letting me know some other solution if someone knows it).

```js
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
// ...

export default (router: VueRouter) => {
  return new Store({
  // router = Vue.observable(router) // You can either do that...
  super({
    state: {
      // router // ... or add `router` to `store` if You need it to be reactive.
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  })
}
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import createStore from './store'
// ...

new Vue({
  router,
  store: createStore(router),
  render: createElement => createElement(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

### Initial answer content

I personally just made a wrapper for a typical `Store` class.

```js
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
// ...

export default class extends Store<any> {
  constructor (router: VueRouter) {
    // router = Vue.observable(router) // You can either do that...
    super({
      state: {
        // router // ... or add `router` to `store` if You need it to be reactive.
        // ...
      },
      // ...
    })
  }
}
```

If You need `$route` You can just use `router.currentRoute`. Just remember You rather need `router` reactive if You want Your `getters` with `router.currentRoute` to work as expected.

And in "main.ts" (or ".js") I just use it with `new Store(router)`.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Store from './store'
// ...

new Vue({
  router,
  store: new Store(router),
  render: createElement => createElement(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```