# VueJs: cannot use router.push

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

So, i want to vue router.push on my store.js, but i keep getting error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

i've tried to import vue-router in my store.js, but still in vain

here's my app.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

//Import and install the VueRouter plugin with Vue.use()
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import App from './views/App'
import Home from './views/Home'
import Login from './views/Login.vue'
import Register from './views/Register.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home,
            meta: { requiresAuth: true }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            name: 'register',
            component: Register
        },
    ],
});



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router,
});
```

and here's my store.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        accessToken: null,
        loggingIn: false,
        loginError: null
    },

    mutations: {
        loginStart: state => state.loggingIn = true,
        loginStop: (state, errorMessage) => {
            state.loggingIn = false;
            state.loginError = errorMessage;
        },
        updateAccessToken: (state, accessToken) => {
            state.accessToken = accessToken;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.accessToken = null;
        }
    },

    actions: {
        doLogin({ commit }, loginData) {
            commit('loginStart');
            console.log(loginData)

            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/login', loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    let accessToken = response.data.jwt;
                    document.cookie = 'jwt_access_token=' + accessToken;
                    commit('updateAccessToken', accessToken);

                    ///this caused the error
                    this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // commit('loginStop', error.response.data.error);
                    console.log(error)
                    commit('updateAccessToken', null);
                    console.log(error.response);
                })
        }
    }
})
```

as you can see, after i call doLogin() function, and using axios, it stop at the this.$router.push({ path: '/' }) line, causing error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate using vue router from Vuex actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736799/how-to-navigate-using-vue-router-from-vuex-actions)

Comment: Where did you add the store to your Vue instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a `router.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  ...
})

export default router
```

In `app.js` replace the import of the vue-router to your new `router.js` and remove `Vue.use(Router)`.

In the store, `this` is not the Vue instance. 
Import the `router.js` in your `store.js`;

```
import router from './router'
```

Then you can access it like this;

```
router.push({ path: '/' })
```

I also noticed that you haven't add the store to the Vue instance. Import and add in `app.js`.

```
import store from './store'

...

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router,
    store //<<<<<<<<
});
```