# router not defined when calling inside a vuex action

Tags: laravel, vuex, vue-router

Am using Vuex in my Laravel app and for some reason, I cannot do route.push inside an action.

My app.js:
    require('./bootstrap');

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import { routes } from './routes'

import store from './store/store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

Vue.component('app-component', require('./App.vue').default);
Vue.component('appRegister', require('./components/User/Register.vue').default);
Vue.component('appLogin', require('./components/User/Login.vue').default);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store
});
```

Inside my Login controller, I have a method called login which looks like the following:

```
login(){
    this.$store.dispatch('login', this.user);
}
```

Then my login action looks like this:

```
login: ({commit}, user) => {
    state.users.map(u => {
        if(u.email == user.email){
            router.push('/');
        } 
    });        
}
```

When I click on the button, I see the following error in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: router is not defined"
```

Note, if I do the following inside the Component method, it works fine:

```
login(){
    this.$router.push('/');
}
```

How can I do the route push inside the vuex action?

I looked at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736799/how-to-navigate-using-vue-router-from-vuex-actions/40736916) but it does not seem to solve my problem.
I imported vue-router inside app.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your vue router in your login controller or import your router into your login controller.